# Order by clause is changing my result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I know why it's happening but I want to find a way around it if possible.

For example I have 4 rows in my database and each has a datetime (which are all different). What I want to do is get the latest 2 rows but use ascending order, so that the oldest is at the top of the result set.

I currently am using

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM mytable
WHERE someid = @something
ORDER BY added DESC
```

This gets me the correct rows but in the wrong order. If I change the DESC to ASC it gets the right order, but the older two of the four rows. This all makes sense to me but is there a way around it?

EDIT: Solved with Elliot's answer below. The syntax would not work without setting an alias for the derived table however. Here is the result

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT TOP 2 * FROM mytable WHERE someid = @something ORDER BY added DESC) AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.added ASC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd think one brute-force solution would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM mytable WHERE someid = @something ORDER BY added DESC)
ORDER BY added
```

Comment: I get a syntax error at the end ORDER BY clause 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. Do I need a WHERE clause to use order by?

Comment: Nevermind fixed it. I added 'AS tbl' to the end of the bracketed select statment, and then ORDER BY tbl.added

Answer (score 5):

This will allow "top 2 per something" with a PARTITION BY added to the OVER clause

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY added DESC) as rn
  FROM mytable
  WHERE someid = @something
  ) foo
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY added
```

Note that the derived table requires an alias

Comment: What are the advantages to this method over Elliot Nelson's above?

Comment: @James Hay: honestly, none, apart from extendible for "top n per group" type queries, or more complex sorting.

Comment: Well it works well enough so upvotes to you. But I think for the sake of brevity I will go with the above one.